# How to get current Profile Provider in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ninject, profile-provider

I'm using Ninject to inject repository into my Membership provider and Roles provider, so my code for this is:

```
public class SystemAdminsRolesProvider : ClientRoleProvider
{
    [Inject]
    public ICenterRepository DBRepository { get; set; }

    //......
}
```

and in the Ninject control factory I call:

```
kernel = new StandardKernel();
kernel.Inject(Membership.Provider);
kernel.Inject(Roles.Provider);
```

so the dependency will be injected to both Membership and Roles providers.

The point is I can easily find the CURRENT providers for Membership and Roles, but how can I find the current provider for the Profile!!???

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it, it's:

```
System.Web.Profile.ProfileManager.Provider
```

Thanks,